# The set $\mathbb Z$ is equinumerous with the set of positive even numbers.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm trying to prove the statement provided in the title, but I can't find a mapping between the two sets. Any hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

One way to do it is $0\to 2,-1\to 4,1\to 6,-2\to 8, 2\to 10, \dots.$ Thus we have 
$f(0)=2$ and $f(z)=-4z$ for $z<0.$ Can you define $f(z)$ for $z>0?$